# Derive the variance of the standardized normal of sample mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

I have solved the following problem and felt a little bit uncertain about the my answer.
Here is the problem.

Let $Y_i \in L_{2}$ for $i=1,2,...,N$  be a scalar random variable with iid with $\mu_Y=E(Y_i)$ and $\sigma_Y^2=var(Y_i) \lt \infty$. The sample average is defined as $\overline{Y_N}=\sum Y_i/N$.

Suppose that $Z_N= \frac{\overline{Y_N}-E(\overline{Y_N})}{\sqrt{(var(\overline{Y_N}))}}$

Derive $Var(Z_N)$

If the limit of $Z_N$ exists, it will be nondegenerate. How can I derive $Var(Z_N)$?
At first glimpse, I think $Var(Z_N)$ is equal to 1.

1.) However, can we use the moment generating function to prove that $Var(Z_N)$=1. If yes, what I have to do is just to show that the moment generating function of $Z_N$ is similar to the moment generating function of the standard normal?

2.) Is this also a link to Chi square?

Helps and comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Because variance is bilinear and invariant under additive shifts, $$\operatorname{Var}(Z_N)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\bar Y_N)}}\right)^{2}\operatorname{Var}(\bar Y_N)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $Var(Z_N) = 1$.

Here is the proof:
First,
$$
\begin{align}
E[\bar{Y_N}] &= E[\frac{1}{N} \sum Y_i] \\
             &= \frac{1}{N} \sum E[Y_i] \\
             &= \frac{1}{N} N\mu = \mu,
\end{align}
$$
since the expectation operator $E[]$ is linear.

Next:
$$
\begin{align}
Var(\bar{Y_N}) &= Var(\frac{1}{N}\sum_i Y_i)\\
               &= \frac{1}{N^2} \, Var(\sum_i Y_i)\\
               &= \frac{1}{N^2} \, N \, Var(Y_i)\\
               &= \frac{1}{N} \, \sigma^2,
\end{align}
$$
where the third equation follows because the [Bienayme's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bienaym%C3%A9%27s_identity) and because the sample is iid.

Thus we have:
$$
Z_N = \frac{\bar{Y_N} - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}}.
$$
The variance of $Z_N$ can now be computed as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
Var(Z_N) &= Var\left(\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_i Y_i - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}}\right)\\
         &=Var\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_i Y_i - \sqrt{N}\mu}{\sigma}\right)\\
         &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2} Var\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_i Y_i\right)\\
         &= \frac{1}{N\sigma^2} N \sigma^2\\
         &= 1.
\end{align}
$$
The third equation follows because the variance is quadratic w.r.t. constant factors and invariant w.r.t. simple shifts (here we have a shift by $\sqrt{N}\mu$). In the fourth equation we used, again, Bienaymé's identity.

Comment: This answer doesn't need more than a single line of algebra and, because it is so unnecessarily involved, really obscures the point.  See my comment to the question.

Comment: Thank you every one.